# Merge [javascript] and [jquery] tags

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, retag-request, synonym-request, fun

There is often confusion among beginners. Most of the time, when they ask a **JavaScript** question, what they really want is **JQuery**. In fact, every problem can be solved with JQuery.

We should make [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) a synonym of [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) and merge the two.

Comment: Now that's an April Fools that may trick some people :)

Comment: Without the fun tag it'll be hard to find this later to delete it.

Comment: @Lix taken care of (after peer review) ... I wonder if an increase in rep could solve this. brb mining unicoins.

Comment: @rlemon - The unicorn rep does not affect privileges ... or does it? No, it really doesn't.

Comment: @TravisJ all of that mining. and it doesn't effect privileges. What a sham.

Comment: Congratulations on the first april fools post that is actually funny. Its only taken all-fricking-day

Comment: @RichardTingle It's also the first April Fools' post that doesn't involve unicorns, I'm more proud of that achievement.

Comment: I think a "status-completed" is a bad tag here, I think "status-declined" would be the correct option.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

That sounds reasonable. It's about time everyone [dropped Javascript and tried jQuery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssRUr.gif).

Comment: I don't even... I just... April Fools.. Ha?.... ***NO!!!***

Comment: I thought javascript and jQuery were the same thing?  Can't we just delete javascript tag altogether?

Comment: People get this wrong all the time. jQuery is a programming language focused on querying. JavaScript is just scripting in Java. It's possible to implement the JavaScript pattern using the jQuery language and it's actually quite common. As Douglas Crockford once put it "jQuery is da bomb lolz".

Comment: And it's spelled Jake Weary, not jQuery

Comment: I wish I could ban jquery from search results, so much noise

Comment: @SuperUberDuper search for `[javascript] -[jquery]`?

Answer (score 12):

I agree. There is no point in using esoteric javascript when the new jQuery language is available.

jQuery should be used everywhere especially when creating native applications on mobile devices.

jQuery jQuery jQuery bacon. Javascript is only for scripting, jQuery is for everything else.

Comment: jQuery is not a language, it's a library.

Comment: jQuery jQuery jQuery jQuery jQuery jQuery jQuery jQuery jQuery jQuery jQuery jQuery.

Comment: @BlueIce Scrip-ting Scrip-ting

Comment: @BlueIce HODOR HODOR HODOR!

Comment: I believe, there is not point in using java when we have new languages like Spring, Hibernate , jUnit languages. Why they even having new version for Java 8

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately there are still a few legacy COBOL systems out there running JavaScript (mostly corporate financial systems). These older systems aren't powerful enough to run the full jQuery stack, so we may need to keep the JavaScript tag around for a while longer.

Comment: `jQuery.noCOBOLConflictMode();` solves this

Comment: This makes perfect sense! I heard JavaScript is still used in space...

Comment: @VisioN yes we use it alot, we used Javascript 1000 years ago...